# Не работает сортировка выбора

Tags: массивы, сортировка-выбором

Мне нужно отсортировать массив С по возрастанию методом выбора, но код выдает такую ошибку:

> Stack around the variable "C" was corrupted.

```
#include <ctime>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    int C[21], min, iMin, j, i;

    cout << "Array C : " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)

    {

        C[i] = rand() % 71 - 50;

        cout << C[i] << ", ";

    }

    cout << "\b\b";

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)

    {

        min = C[i];

        iMin = i;

        for (j = i; j < 21; j++)

        {

            if (C[j] < min)

            {

                min = C[j];

                iMin = j;

            }

        }

        C[iMin] = C[i];

        C[j] = min;

    }

    cout << "\nSort array C : \n";

    for (i = 0; i < 21; i++)

    {

        cout << C[i] << ", ";

    }

}
```